# How to use azure app service configuration during development

Tags: .net, azure, configuration

Firstly wanna point out that I'm quite new to azure in general (3 days old Junior).

I have a .NET Framework 4.5.2 app that holds database connection string in Web.config file
as :

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="db connection string here" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When deploying to Azure as an App Service, I override that configuration by: in the portal.azure.com -> select that App Service -> Configuration -> Connection strings -> New connection string name: DBConnectionString value: db connection string.

And it works fine, when running locally I have connection string from Web.config, when deployed to Azure it uses connection string from App Service Configuration.

**My question is**: Is it possible to always use App Service Configuration from Azure, even if running app locally on IIS Express during development? If yes, how?

Thanks for reading this far, and If the question is dumb than I'm really sorry, I just don't know much about Azure yet.

Comment: Consider using Azure App Configuration - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview. Key Vault pairs well with it for management of secrets as well.